# CiviCRM WordPress OAuth2 Google Workspace Labeling

Tags: wordpress, oauth

CiviCRM v5.62.0 WordPress v6.2.2 OAuth2 working properly.

My problem is that it labels ALL of my email either label:inbox-civimail-ignored (none yet) or label:inbox-civimail-processed (all thus far). When this happens it clears out the inbox, marks everything read and I have to select All Mail to view my emails and then try to figure out what is what. We rarely have any email related to CiviCRM, but have to make sure we do not miss a new registration or whatnot. Deleting the labels does nothing because ANY email that comes in triggers this labeling.

Where can I go in the code to get rid of this labeling?

Thank you!

[image: CiviCRM Applied Labels]

Comment: Is there somewhere else I can ask the question as this is a pretty important issue in that the code that CiviCRM provides creates an all or nothing facet. For example, could someone tell me how to find the OAuth file that controls this and perhaps hack that file to fix my issue?

Comment: generally we set up specific email addresses for civi to do its processing in (eg for Bounces), but you may be doing something that I haven't dealt with. Can you update your post to give a bit more context as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a single email operating under Google Workspace. In order for CiviCRM to work with Google Workspace it requires OAuth. To do that and in order to receive inbound emails I submit that to Google Cloud, all of which works. The labelling is the issue. The bounce operates under an alias as we cannot afford multiple paid workforce accounts. Thanx

Comment: Testing something that @petednz-fuzion made me think about. If correct, I will attribute the solution to him IN RE: simply using a different email address. If not, then I will add more.

Comment: By changing the Bounce email to a different email address, in this case a simple Gmail and not Google Workspace, I can report that it still triggers the labelling. I can also report that in the new email account (Gmail and not Workspace). I do not know if this works with Microsoft or say Roundcube if you are self hosting with cPanel or any others. So, I am right back to square one although I thought it worked yesterday. ;(

Comment: can you add a screenshot for what is here /civicrm/admin/mailSettings?reset=1

Comment: Requested Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/qY8o5yX | Screenshot for Mail Accounts: https://imgur.com/a/0hmVq7B

Comment: the link i gave may only work for Drupal. not sure what CMS you are on. can you add a screenshot of what you see via the civi admin menu at Administer > CiviMail > MailAccounts

Comment: This is a copy to the screenshot:  https://imgur.com/a/EMjPpnc I am noting that the difference between the original for Mail Accounts and this one is that the Domain remained iafst.org in the old one and the new one is gmail.com

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I believe the changing of the bounce domain name may have fixed the issue, but will have to confirm later this afternoon as it has a habit of resurrecting itself. Here is the latest screenshot showing new emails and NO labelling. Screenshot: https://imgur.com/FC42EFx

Comment: Nope. Back again as I feared. :( Screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/YuZNvtz

Comment: not sure i can help more. I have never seen 'Protocol = maildir'. our has always been set up as imap for gmail

Comment: So, maildir works fine. When we use IMAP it kicks back "An error occured while sending or receiving mail. The IMAP server did not accept the username and/or password: A0001 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure). (See log for more details.)" This is why OAuth2 was brought out. Let me ask this, though. Bounce is not important to us due to size. Why couldn't I just turn off the fetch_bounces scheduled job? Would this impact anything other than zombie emails which in the 8yrs thus far, we have never gotten an email that way in the logs. Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the Bounce email to a different email address, in this case a simple Gmail and not Google Workspace, I can report that it does nothing. It is worthy to note that fundamentally, our issue is that we pay enough money for the branded email and domain as it is. So, as using an alias wasn't financially sound, it ended there.

What worked was simply shutting off the Scheduled Job, Process Inbound Emails (API call: fetch_activities). Like I say, we are not dealing with tens of thousands of folks yet and when we do, we will simply buy the new email and turn the jobs back on.

I attribute the solution to @petednz-fuzion for making me understand that it was the Bounce email address that may have caused the original issue! Thank you, sir!